# How to Apply swipe to dismiss feature in friendlychat app in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

This is the List View Builder of Chat Messages below here--

```
 child: new ListView.builder(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: _messages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) => _messages[index]),
      ),
```

Here I defined  `_messages` as under--

```
 final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
```

But When I am Applying "Dismissible" Widget in this, It iS not PIcking Up that correctly..
Here Is What I did..

```
child: new ListView.builder(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: _messages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) => _messages[index]){
              return new Dismissible(
        key: new Key(_messages[index]),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          items.removeAt(index);
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
            content: new Text("Item is Dismissed"),
          ));
        },
        background: new Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
        child: new ListTile(
          title: new Text("${_messages[index]}")
        )
      );
            }
```

But IT IS Showing error. Please Help me in this!!

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: The code looks okay and similar to the one mentioned in the cookbook: https://flutter.io/cookbook/gestures/dismissible/. Can you share the error here?

Comment: the error is that while writing _messeages[index] in key part of listView Builder...It is showing that list<chatMessages> cis not a string